# Spin 1/2 wavefunction transformation under inversion and mirror symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, quantum-spin, group-theory, spinors

I'm considering group-theory applications to condensed matter physics now. In particular I work with the following paper: http://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.100.580 and try to understand the concept of double groups.

Let $G$ be the symmetry group considered (just some group, not the one in the paper) and let $g$ be some element of $G$.

Suppose there are no mirror symmetries and no inversion in group $G$.

As I know, in this case action of $g$ on spin 1/2 two component wavefunction $\phi$ is defined (following for example book "Symmetry and Strain-induced Effects in Semiconductors" by G.L. Bir, G.E. Pikus)  as
$$D(g)\phi(\vec{r})=D_{1/2}(g)\phi(g^{-1}\vec{r})$$
Here $D_{1/2}$ is two dimensional irreducible representation of rotation group.

But now suppose, that the symmetry group $G$ contains an inversion $I$, or, as in the paper above, mirror symmetry $\sigma$.
How do we define $D_{1/2}(I)$ or $D_{1/2}(\sigma)$ in this case (I understand that $\sigma=C_2I$,so it's enough to define one on them)? My intuition says that there are two ways to define these objects. For $I$, for example, $D_{1/2}(I)=E$ or $D_{1/2}(I)=-E$, where $E$ is unit matrix $(E)_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$.

What consideration is correct, and what definition is applied in the paper above?